# Joining one table multiple times with null FKs

Tags: sql, database

In a situation where I have two tables:

- Games(id, player1Id, player2Id)
- Players(id, gender)

And I would like to select all of the games and the player's gender, how would I get around null playerIds?

From [this explanation](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/multiple-joins-to-the-same-table-in-a-query), I would think the answer would be:

```
SELECT Games.id, p1.gender, p2.gender
FROM Games JOIN Players p1 on player1Id = p1.id 
JOIN Players p2 on player2Id = p2.id
```

However, this does not return any game that has either player1Id or player2Id as null. Is there a way to show all games with players connected *when possible*?

Thanks.

Comment: `Games.player1Id` can be `NULL` and and `Games.player2Id` can be `NULL`? That sounds like a design flaw to me i.e. this is not a table because it has no key. I think you need to find a different way of modelling solo player games and two player games.

Comment: @onedaywhen This isn't an actual database. I made up the example tables just so that I could ask the question. Just curious because I've run into this problem before.

Comment: You'd be surprised how often difficult to write SQL DML ('queries') is a result of bad SQL DDL ('table design'). Data element names used in SQL DDL can reveal much about the designer's intention. So give us a chance and post the actual schema :) Otherwise, the schema may be fine and rather it is your recall that is faulty ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN:

```
   SELECT g.id, p1.gender, p2.gender
     FROM Games g
LEFT JOIN Players p1 ON p1.id = g.player1Id
LEFT JOIN Players p2 on p2.id = g.player2Id
```

Here's a [really good link that visual demonstrates the different JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks and great article. The only thing I had left to google was the difference between LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER/INNER JOIN to find that OUTER is default. Thanks again.

Comment: @mphair: Yeah, I find the "OUTER" part to be verbose myself.  What database is this for?

Comment: Nothing in particular, just made up the tables to fit the question. Special curiosity-driven-database, I guess. =P